# Как, используя полиморфизм, избавиться от диспетчеризации в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, полиморфизм

На данный момент класс выглядит следующим образом:

```
from enum import Enum

# Три вспомогательных класса
class SensorType(Enum):
    GYRO = 'gyro'
    ACCL = 'accl'

class Axis(Enum):
    X = 'x'
    Y = 'y'
    Z = 'z'

class SensorValue:
   def __init__(self, value):
     if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
         raise Exception("Введён не верный тип данных")
     if not (-1 <= value <= 1):
         raise Exception("Вышли за пределы допустимого интервала")
     self._value = value

   @property
   def value(self):
       return self._value

# Основной класс датчика
class Sensor:
    def scale(self, sensor_type, axis, value):
        if not (isinstance(sensor_type, SensorType) or isinstance(axis, Axis) \
            or isinstance(value, SensorValue)):
            raise Exception("Введён не верный тип данных")

        if sensor_type == SensorType.GYRO:
            if axis == Axis.X:
                print('do something with SensorType = GYRO, axis = X')
            elif axis == Axis.Y:
                print('do something with SensorType = GYRO, axis = Y')
            elif axis == Axis.Z:
                print('do something with SensorType = GYRO, axis = Z')

        elif sensor_type == SensorType.ACCL:
            if axis == Axis.X:
                print('do something with SensorType = ACCL, axis = X')
            elif axis == Axis.Y:
                print('do something with SensorType = ACCL, axis = Y')
            elif axis == Axis.Z:
                print('do something with SensorType = ACCL, axis = Z')

        return f'{sensor_type}, {axis}, {value.value}'
```

Чтобы передать значения методу scale, его нужно вызывать следующим образом: `sensor.scale(SensorType.GYRO, Axis.X, SensorValue(1))`. Как, используя полиморфизм, упростить вызов до `sensor.scale(GYRO, X, 1)`?

Comment: Наверное, имеется в виду, что нужно сделать классы-наследники SensorGyro и SensorAccl от родительского класса Sensor. Тогда при создании объекта он уже автоматически будет знать, какого он вида сенсор. Ну и методы можно которые разные те реализовать в потомках, а которые одинаковые оставить в предке.

Comment: Дело в том, что это один датчик, но по номеру регистра я могу обращаться и к гироскопу и к акселерометру и мне не всегда нужно использовать метод scale, поэтому  у меня один класс сенсор и чтение данных происходит так: `sensor.y_gyro` или `sensor.y_accl`). По названию метода вызывается геттер в котором указан необходимый адрес данных.

Comment: Даже если это физически один датчик, ничего не мешает создать отдельные классы для гироскопа и акселерометра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> упростить вызов до sensor.scale(GYRO, X, 1)

так не получится и это не то, что имелось ввиду.

Речь о том, что можно избавится от явной проверки типов и использовать полиморфизм, чтобы реализовать разное поведение в зависимости от типа объекта. Это выгодно, если методов типа `scale` много и в каждом нужно реализовывать проверку типа. А если еще эти типы могут добавляться, то поддержка кода еще сильнее усложняется. В таком случае имеет смысл использовать полиморфизм. Ну а если `scale` это единственное место где у вас проверка на тип, то, наверно, смысла особого нет - усложнение может быть неоправданным.

Еще замечание по терминологии: это не избавление от диспечеризации (т.е. от направления потока выполнения в зависимости от условий), а использование другого механизма (а именно полиморфизма вместо явных проверок типа) для диспечеризации.

Если датчик один, но внутри себя содержит и гироскоп и акселерометр, то может иметь смысл отобразить это в коде:

```
class Gyro:
  def scale(self, axis, value):
     if not (isinstance(axis, Axis) or isinstance(value, SensorValue)):
        raise Exception("Введён не верный тип данных")

     if axis == Axis.X:
          print('do something with gyro, axis = X')
     elif axis == Axis.Y:
          print('do something with gyro, axis = Y')
     elif axis == Axis.Z:
           print('do something with gyro, axis = Z')

class Accelerometr:
  def scale(self, axis, value):
    ...

class Sensor:
  def __init__(self):
     self.gyro = Gyro()
     self.accel = Accelerometr()

  
sensor.gyro.scale(Axis.X, SensorValue(0.5))
```

Теперь `enum` `SensorType` не нужен вообще. Он представлен в виде отдельных объектов классов с одинаковым интерфейсом (т.е. `scale` с одинаковой сигнатурой). И теперь у типа датчика есть не только, собственно тип, а еще и поведение в виде метода `scale`.

Если код усложняется, то некоторое общее поведение можно вынести в базовый класс:

```
class SensorSubComponent:
  def scale(self, axis, value):
     if not (isinstance(axis, Axis) or isinstance(value, SensorValue)):
        raise Exception("Введён не верный тип данных")
     if axis == Axis.X:
          self.scale_x(value.value)
     elif axis == Axis.Y:
          self.scale_y(value.value)
     elif axis == Axis.Z:
          self.scale_z(value.value)
    

class Gyro(SensorSubComponent):
  def scale_x(self, value):
     print('do something with gyro, axis = X')
  def scale_y(self, value):
     print('do something with gyro, axis = Y')
  def scale_z(self, value):
     print('do something with gyro, axis = Z')

class Accelerometr(SensorSubComponent):
  def scale_x(self, value):
     print('do something with gyro, axis = X')
  def scale_y(self, value):
     print('do something with gyro, axis = Y')
  def scale_z(self, value):
     print('do something with gyro, axis = Z')
```

Опять же это имеет смысл, если код и логика усложняется.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение!